Mixed order of operations in code that calls util.js
I have a snippet of code that calls a separate util.js file to grab a given text file and read it and create an array from its contents:
function getDataFromTxt(fullFilePath) {
  //gets a list from a txt file and returns 1 array
  const myRequest = new Request(fullFilePath);
  var toReturn;

  fetch(myRequest)
      .then((response) => {
          if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error(`HTTP error, status = ${response.status}`);
          }
          return response.text();
    })
    .then((text) => {
      toReturn = text;
      toReturn = toReturn.split("\r");
      for (let i = 0; i < toReturn.length; i++){
          toReturn[i] = toReturn[i].replace('\n','');
      }
      console.log(toReturn);
      return toReturn;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      toReturn = `Error: ${error.message}`;
    });
}

However, when its called, the order of operations of what is going on really has me confused...
console.log("before");
this.patrolArray = getDataFromTxt(textFile);
console.log("after");

This results in the console spitting out:
before
after
<array>

Am I having a brain fart here or is something going on that I'm not expecting. I am relatively new to JS so apologies if this is a dumb question.

Your getDataFromText() function doesn't return anything, and on top of that, it can't return the result of the fetch.

@Pointy What does that mean it can't return the result of the fetch? If I move the console.log and return lines outside the fetch, the order seems to work but the console log says that toReturn is undefined. I'm assuming this is what you're referring to?

You can't (and shouldn't) rely on modifying an external variable from inside a fetch's then method. Consider returning the fetch itself and accessing the variable using .then

@Kyle: getDataFromTxt is performing an asynchronous operation.  It would either need to return a Promise which can be awaited to resolve to the result, or whatever operation(s) need to occur after the asynchronous operation would need to be in the .then() callback(s) you already have.  Currently getDataFromTxt itself never returns anything.  It invokes fetch (the asynchronous operation) and then immediately exits.  All synchronous code completes before any asynchronous operations are followed up.

OK that makes sense. But how would I return the fetch itself?
Or how would I use a Promise? The last hour I spent trying to figure out what it is / how to use it but I'm not any closer.

@Kyle: The linked questions contain a lot more information on the subject.  But essentially if your function does: return fetch(/* ... */) then it returns the Promise that fetch itself returns.  Then you could either use await getDataFromTxt(textFile) to get the result of that Promise or follow it with a callback just like you do with fetch, for example: getDataFromTxt(textFile).then(result => { /* do something with the result */ });
